# How to select nodes which contain a string in their class name with XPath in C#?

Tags: c#, html, css, xpath

I have span nodes with class atrribute like this:

```
<span class=" cite fw-xl fz-ms lh-17">www.azlyrics.com</span>
<span class=" fz-ms fw-m fc-12th wr-bw lh-17">www.imdb.com</span>
```

I want to access all of thes elements with thoes class property. I write this code but it returns `null`:

```
node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class,'lh-17')]").InnerText;
```

How should I get both of these elements?

Comment: http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/html-parser

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you

```
string XmlContent = "<span class=\" cite fw-xl fz-ms lh-17\">www.azlyrics.com</span><span class=\" fz-ms fw-m fc-12th wr-bw lh-17\">www.imdb.com</span>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root>" + XmlContent + "</root>");
XmlNode newNode = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList ab = newNode.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@class, 'lh-17')]");

foreach (XmlNode k in ab)
{
   Console.WriteLine(k.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: tnx. but I do not have just these two span tags It was as an example.I have a html page and I load it. then just in foreach `node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class,'lh-17')]").InnerText;` returns `NULL` while I have 10 span tags which contain `'lh-17'`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are multiple spans in this solution. Just load them into the XmlContent string variable, and remember that you have to use SelectNodes and not SelectSingleNode